# what's the differences between sendOrNothing vs trySend of Coroutine Channel?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-coroutine-channel

I wanted to know how to pass lifeCycleScope or viewModelScope to `WebSocketListener` class.

And I couldn't find the solution and ended up to using GlobalScope like below:

```
override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        socketEventChannel.sendOrNothing(SocketUpdate(exception = t))
    }
}
```

And I've found there's `trySend` for channel like below.

```
override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
    socketEventChannel.trySend(SocketUpdate(exception = t))
}
```

What's the difference? Do they have any pros and cons? And which way is better?